# How can I make my switch statement more performant

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a switch statement for multiple types of enums and I check based on the type, whether or not a timestamp that corresponds to that type is within a provided date-range. I use 10 switches and wanted to know if there was a query function that's more performant.

Is it possible to use a selectmany or where from linq to make this more performant?

```
private Event[] FilterNotifications(Event[] eventResponseItems, DateTime beginDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var eventList = eventResponseItems.ToList();
    foreach (var eEvent in eventList)
    {
        switch (eEvent.EventType)
        {
            case "RouteStarted":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Started))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "RouteDeparted":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Arrived))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "RouteArrived":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Completed))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "RouteCompleted":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Departed))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "StopArrived":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.ArrivalTimeStamp))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "StopDeparted":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.DepartureTimeStamp))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "StopServicing":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.ArrivalTimeStamp))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "StopCancelled":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.DepartureTimeStamp))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;

            case "RouteStatusChanged":
                if (!InRange(beginDate, endDate, eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.ArrivalTimeStamp))
                    eventList.Remove(eEvent);
                break;
        }
    }

    return eventList.ToArray();
}

private bool InRange(DateTime beginTime, DateTime endTime, string timeStamp)
{
    DateTime timeStmp = DateConverter.ToInternal(timeStamp).Value;
    if ( timeStmp >= beginTime)
    {
        if (endTime != new DateTime() && timeStmp <= endTime)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Without really knowing what you're doing here I observe that you appear to be querying a date range within a loop where the range delimiters are invariant. Perhaps you can create a sub-range outside the loop, before considering the event type, and query only that subrange within the loop?

Comment: Is the code having a performance issue?  I was just curious if this was a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Since all code paths inside the first `if` condition return `true` (in the `InRange` method), there isn't a need for the nested `if` statement (or the second `return true;` should be `return false;`)

Comment: The code looks fine, I don't see how a `Linq` method would make performance any better.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError your name made my heart skip a beat.

Comment: @RufusL ah well thanks

Comment: Aside from Travis' answer, the `if` block within your `InRange` returns `true` regardless of which branch it takes. You can simply `return timeStmp >= beginTime;` at this point, but it may not be your intention. (More of an observation than a direct answer to your question of performance.)

Comment: The `switch` *in release mode* will use clever programming in the compiler to be really fast. Don't do anything to defeat that, like making it look up something else.

Comment: In general LINQ is few times slower than plain C# (probably due to overhead from enumerators and lambda expressions), so performance and LINQ tags are quite contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be far more concerned with the *maintainability* of your code than the *performance*. If we start by just trying to remove repetitive code, and make the remaining code easy to understand, I'd end up with something like this:

```
private Event[] FilterNotifications(Event[] eventResponseItems, DateTime beginDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return eventResponseItems
        .Where(e => InRange(beginDate, endDate, GetEventRouteTimeStampFromEventType(e.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps, e.EventType)))
        .ToArray();
}

private string GetEventRouteTimeStampFromEventType(RouteTimeStamps routeTimeStamps, string eventType)
{
    switch (eventType)
    {
        case "RouteStarted":
        case "StopCancelled":
            return routeTimestamps.Started;

        case "RouteDeparted":
            return routeTimestamps.Arrived;

        case "RouteArrived":
            return routeTimestamps.Completed;

        case "RouteCompleted":
            return routeTimestamps.Departed;


        case "StopDeparted":
            return routeTimestamps.DepartureTimeStamp;

        case "RouteStatusChanged":
        case "StopServicing":
        case "StopArrived":
            return routeTimestamps.ArrivalTimeStamp;

        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

And, in fact, this happens to get better performance, too (since you're filtering as you go, rather than creating a list and removing items from it). So that's a nice win.

Note that I've made the presumption that you've got a limited list of event types, and you want to throw an exception if you see anything else (which is usually the case when you're choosing a switch statement). If that's not the case, you could do something like returning null instead, and tweak the remaining code accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really much to optimize performance wise in your method, as it doesn't use any complicated iteration.

You could use a dictionary for this from a readability standpoint. This will also allow you to avoid fully materializing the returned Array by using `.Where()`.

You will need a slightly complicated `Func<>` as seen below in order to convert the event info enum for each event into the timestamp string.

```
var RouteControl = new Dictionary<string,Func<Event,string>>()
{
    { "RouteStarted"       , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Started },
    { "RouteDeparted"      , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Arrived },
    { "RouteArrived"       , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Completed },
    { "RouteCompleted"     , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.RouteInfo.RouteTimestamps.Departed },
    { "StopArrived"        , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.ArrivalTimeStamp },
    { "StopDeparted"       , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.DepartureTimeStamp },
    { "StopServicing"      , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.ArrivalTimeStamp },
    { "StopCancelled"      , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.DepartureTimeStamp },
    { "RouteStatusChanged" , eEvent => eEvent.EventInfo.StopInfo.ArrivalTimeStamp }       
};

return eventResponseItems.Where(eEvent => 
    !RouteControl.ContainsKey(eEvent.EventType) ||
    InRange(beginDate, endDate, RouteControl[eEvent.EventType](eEvent))
).ToArray();
```

Comment: @RufusL - To be honest, I was just fixing that. I did the negation improperly at first since it started as a conversion from Remove and needed to be negated.

Comment: In fact it has to be `!`, but `&&` must be `||`.

Comment: @IvanStoev - The case where the Dictionary misses had to be in there too, which made it a little awkward.

Comment: Then you don't need the second `ContainsKey` check, do you?

Comment: This makes the original code about an order of magnitude slower.  The OP will never discover this by himself, he didn't check whether he actually had a perf problem.  He doesn't.

Comment: @HansPassant - Why is it an order of magnitude slower?

Comment: Also it's not only for readability. But the Dictionary should be moved to a private static readonly field/property, so it is allocated only once. Thus, along with the eliminating the `ToList()` and especially `Remove` (linear search and probably the slowest part of the original code) should give the desired performance improvement.

Comment: I never really scoped the Dictionary since it can be hard to directly state what architecture people should use. Just noting that this approach would be ideal. If you want to expand it into a separate method that works too (as in the other answer). I agree though @Ivan, the next step would be to address scoping and architecture.

Comment: Well, allocation of the Dictionary in every call is the only thing I can think of why Hans is complaining that the code is slower than the original. Moving it to static initialization won't hurt in any architecture I guess. And in order to be perfect, the two hash searches can be turned into one by using `TryGetValue` method, e.g. `(eEvent => !RouteControl.TryGetValue(eEvent.EventType, out timeStamp) || InRange(beginDate, endDate, timeStamp(eEvent))` :) But +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

List.Remove is in O(n), so your whole loop is in O(n^2). You might improve perfomance if you fill a second list while iterating over the first list that only contains the elements you want.